# css grid fit-content contents out of bounds with vertical writing mode

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using a grid layout consisting of two `div` elements with the following column template:
`fit-content(25%) auto`.

I want to have the first `div` as high as the grid height with a vertically written and centered text in it.
I also want the first `div` to contain a `fieldset`, thus I set `display: flex` and `align-items: stretch` on the `fieldset` so the contained items have the maximum available height.

I set up the following example:

```css
div#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: fit-content(25%) auto;
}

div#first-column > fieldset {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#sideways {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    transform: rotate(0.5turn);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="first-column">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="sideways">
                <a href="#">Sideway Text</a>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="second-column">
        text<br/>
        to<br/>
        make<br/>
        the<br/>
        grid<br/>
        higher<br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the vertical text in the first grid column is out of bounds.
When re-enabling the `text-align: center` property in firefox using the css debugger the text gets rendered correctly.
In chrome the layout changes when re-enabling the box-sizing property.
See the following video:
https://screens.totally.rip/2018/09/vokoscreen-2018-09-25_23-33-02.webm

My guess is that the browser fails to calculate the width of the first grid column because the text is written vertically.
But maybe I'm just not using some css properties correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the bug and it turns out that this is already known. Apparently the child fails to report the correct width because of the orthogonal flow.

See [my bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1494445) and [the underlying issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1166120).

I haven't been able to find a chromium issue for this behavior, but I guess the bug is also already known there.

Note that the firefox and chromium bugs are actually not the same.
The minimal test case I provided with my bug report renders fine in chromium, but the example from my question above doesn't. I guess it has something to do with the flex layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first-column to take up the all width ..try

```
flex:1;
```

In the first-Column div.
But if you want the .first-column
To be on the left side as in asidebar
Set the grid-area and define each then apply to the divs

```
.grid {display:grid;
grid-template-column: ...
grid'template-row:....
  grid-area: 
         "first  first second"
        "first  first second"}
.first-column {grid-area:first}
.Second-column:{grid-area:second}
```

**that is : if you wanted two vertical columns , first bigger  than second  column** 
*notice :have used class (.)but don't mind am typing using ma phone , so it kinda sucks just use your number sign*

Comment: I don't want the first column to take up the full width, I want the first column to be as small as possible and with a maximum width of 25%. That's why I used fit-content(25%). The main problem I have is that the content of the first div is not inside the div. Anyways, thanks for your answer!